# How many elements the output matrix should have in this code?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

I have written the following MATLAB code and as I initialized the matrix `stab1`, I think this matrix should have 4991 elements at the end, but when I run the code, `stab1` has 801445 elements at the end. Is the problem with my code?

```
stab1=zeros(1,4991);
k=0;
for ii=-0.6:0.01:-.3
m=0;
    for jj=0:0.01:1.6
    m=m+1;

    if .... (some condition)
    stab1(k*161+m)=1;
    end

    k=k+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with your code.  You should use the debugger to figure out what that problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the `k=k+1` at a wrong place. It is the correct code:

```
stab1=zeros(1,4991);
k=0;
for ii=-0.6:0.01:-.3
m=0;
    for jj=0:0.01:1.6
    m=m+1;

    if .... (some condition)
    stab1(k*161+m)=1;
    end


    end
 k=k+1; 
 end
```

Now it has 4991 elements.